# How do you detect top of an element is near of the bottom of browser with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you detect top of an element is near of the bottom of browser  with jQuery?

when I scroll down, if bottom of browser reach to top of an specal div,it alert me, and when I scroll up and bottom of browser reach to the top of that div,alert me again?

something like [this website](http://www.etq-amsterdam.com/) when scroll it down or up. (jquery effect)

Comment: Can you place your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: use $scroll method

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for this. you can do this using below code.

```
var ScrollBottom = 100;

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 
    $(document).height() - ScrollBottom) { 
    // your ajax call here
}
```